# Prove that $PQ=2r$

Tags: geometry

Suppose that $ABCD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral within a circle of radius $r$. The bisector of the angle $A$ cuts the circle at point $P$ and the bisector of angle $C$ cuts the circle at point $Q$. Then Prove that $PQ=2r$
So here basically we have to prove that the line segment $PQ$ passes through the center of the circle. And how do we prove that, I don't know. Maybe somewhere that the line segment $PQ$ forms a right angle on the circle but I have not been able to prove that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a construction from the vertex $D$ to the end points of $PQ$, $DQ$ and $DP$.
Taking the sector $DP$ we know the angle subtended at the circumference is equal. That means, $\angle DAP = \angle DQP$ and similarly taking sector $DQ$ we have $\angle DCQ = \angle DPQ$. Now use the fact that opposite angles of a cyclic quadrilateral always add up to 180 degrees and that angles $\angle DAP$ and $\angle DCQ$ are the angle bisectors of the opposite angles $\angle A$ and $\angle C$,

$\implies \angle DQP + \angle DPQ = 90\deg $

In the $\triangle DPQ$, two angles are known, so

$\angle QDP = 180 - 90 = 90\deg$

We know that the angle subtended by a semi-circle at the circumference is 90 degrees, which implies PQ must be the diameter of the circle.

Comment: But I was just wondering if you consider that your triangle $DPQ$ is not a triangle but with center $O$, it forms a quadrilateral $QOPD$, how will you prove this point?

Answer (score 0):

Let $AP$ and $CD$ meet at $F$.Also join $Q$ and $P$ to $B$ and let angles $A = 2a,C =2b,B = x  and  D = y.$
Since angle subtended at the centre = twice angle subtended at the circumference,$AFC = 2 ×\angle B = 2x.$
$x + y = 180$ and $a + b = 90$.
Therefore $a + b + 2x + y = 360$ which is the same as $2x + y = 270 •••••••[1]$
Also since $x + y = 180$ we solve it simultaneously with $[1]$ to arrive at $x = 90°$,which implies $QP$ is a diameter =$2r$